# generating a random string and submit it within the form with an input element

Tags: php, html

I have made a random string generator and I want to submit this string in the form with an input element named STR

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

    $str = $_GET['str'];

}

function RandomStr($length)
{
$str = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

return substr(str_shuffle($str),0,$length);
}

$str = RandomStr(13); //I want to submit this random string with STR input field

?>

<html>
        <body>
            <form action="" method="GET">
               STR: <input type="text" name="str">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </form> 
        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: place this element in form `<input type="hidden" name="STR" value="<?php echo RandomStr(13); ?>">`

Comment: Isn't that what my first duplicate says?